# VB.NET background task pass parameters and use return value in textfields

Tags: vb.net

I am just trying to figure out how to use the Background task, or something equiv, to pass in some parameters to the background task and then get return values from the tasks as they finish and update a text field...

This is what I would like to do at a high level in VB.NET:

1. User clicks button on form
2. HTTP request performed in background thread with some args
3. When response from request is received, update field on form with this data

Here is the code:

```
    Public Class Form1
    Dim WebUpdateWorker As BackgroundWorker

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim arg1 As String = "Hi"
        Dim arg2 As Integer = 1
        WebUpdateWorker = New BackgroundWorker
        AddHandler WebUpdateWorker.DoWork, AddressOf DoWork
        AddHandler WebUpdateWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkFinished
        WebUpdateWorker.RunWorkerAsync()

    End Sub

    Public Function httpTask(ByVal arg1 As String, ByVal arg2 As Integer)
        ' do http request, return the http response
        Return "http response"
    End Function

    Private Sub DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        ' I want to pass these values in instead of hard coding them here
        httpTask("Hi", 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WorkFinished(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        ' I want to use the returned value from httpTask here
        TextBox.Text = ("Result from background job: ")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how I can pass parameters to a background task, and then use the return values from that task in a form field

Comment: RunWorkerAsync() can take an argument, you'll get it back in DoWork as e.Argument.  You can pass any object you need, including one of a little helper class with any number of properties.